# R - leaflet set polygons on top level

Tags: r, leaflet, layer

Good evening, created the following map via leaflet:

```
leaflet(options =  leafletOptions()) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  setView(lng = -45.769325, lat = 45.859322) %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenStreetMap) %>%
  addPolygons(data = geoID, color = 'white',
              weight = 2, smoothFactor = .5,
              fillColor = pal(Color$x),
              highlight = highlightOptions(bringToFront = T, weight = 1, color = 'blue'),
              label = lapply(html_labels2, HTML)) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = vec) %>%
  addPopups(-45.769325, 45.859322, popup)
```

Everything is fine, except the problem that the labels i created are sometimes overlayed by legend and popup, is there a way that the labels `label = lapply(html_labels2, HTML))` show up always on Top, like above legend and popup? Thanks very much in advance.

Edit: Here is a code to reproduce the problem https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/choropleths.html

```
# From http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/us-states.js
states <- geojsonio::geojson_read("json/us-states.geojson", what = "sp")

bins <- c(0, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200, 500, 1000, Inf)
pal <- colorBin("YlOrRd", domain = states$density, bins = bins)

labels <- sprintf(
  "<strong>%s</strong><br/>%g people / mi<sup>2</sup>",
  states$name, states$density
) %>% lapply(htmltools::HTML)

leaflet(states) %>%
  setView(-96, 37.8, 4) %>%
  addProviderTiles("MapBox", options = providerTileOptions(
    id = "mapbox.light",
    accessToken = Sys.getenv('MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'))) %>%
  addPolygons(
    fillColor = ~pal(density),
    weight = 2,
    opacity = 1,
    color = "white",
    dashArray = "3",
    fillOpacity = 0.7,
    highlight = highlightOptions(
      weight = 5,
      color = "#666",
      dashArray = "",
      fillOpacity = 0.7,
      bringToFront = TRUE),
    label = labels,
    labelOptions = labelOptions(
      style = list("font-weight" = "normal", padding = "3px 8px"),
      textsize = "15px",
      direction = "auto")) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~density, opacity = 0.7, title = NULL,
    position = "bottomright")
```

To further illustrate my problem, here a pic. I would like to have the label infront of the legend.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfxPu.png)

Comment: for me, impossible to reproduce/answer without sample data..

Comment: @Wimpel hope that helps to reproduce the problem, thanks for your help.